# string operator overloading in c++ - I really don't get it

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

string& operator+(string & lhs, int & rhs) {
    char temp[255];
    itoa(rhs,temp,10);
    return lhs += temp;
}

int main() {
  string text = "test ";
  string result = text + 10;
}
```

The result is:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:15:26: error: no match for 'operator+' in 'text + 10'
test.cpp:15:26: note: candidates are:
/.../
```

And should be `test 10`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An rvalue (`10`) can't bind to a non-const reference. You need to rewrite your `operator+` to take either an `int const &` or just an `int` as its parameter.

While you're at it, you want to rewrite it so it doesn't modify the left operand either. An `operator +=` should modify its left operand, but an `operator +` should not.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't take the int by reference. Just take it by value. Your problem is that you're trying to take a non-const reference to a literal integer - what would be the meaning of changing a literal?

That said you might consider against creating such an operator as it has a fair chance of confusing future maintainers.